# Merging in JPA / Hibernate based on unique key instead of primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, unique-constraint, jpa-2.1, unique-key

In JPA or Hibernate, is it possible to merge a new entity (that does not have a primary key value) into a persistence context based on a unique key other than the primary key?

Or is all JPA / Hibernate merging only performed on primary keys?

If this isn't possible with a simple method call, are my only options to either:

1. replace the existing primary key with the unique key
2. write code that finds any existing entity using the values of the attributes in the unique key.  If I were to do this, I guess I'd write a static method that looks for `@UniqueConstraint` annotations, and searches for existing entities based on the the attributes in the `@UniqueConstraint`s.  I'd try to merge into the first entity that was found for any of the `@UniqueConstraint`s.  If no matches, then I could just persist the new entity.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate only requires a unique key for the `@Id` property, and, although typically the primary key is used for this purpose, you can use any unique key for the `@Id` property.

More, you can use a primary key for the `@Id` property and a unique key as the `@NaturalId`. You can fetch the entity by its natural-id and then merge it in a different `Session` because merging takes an entity and not an identifier.